# How to find average SRI score within subgroups

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to find the average SRI score within ethnicity groups. What code would I use to do this?
I currently have

```
d1 %>% 
  filter(ethnicity == 'white', na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(avg_sri)
```

which displays a list of sri scores for the 123 white participants; however, I want to get their average SRI score.

How would I do this?

Thank you,
From a beginner and struggling R student!

```
d1 %>% 
  filter(ethnicity == 'black', na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(avg_sri)
```

Comment: `d1 |> group_by(ethnicity) |> summarize(avg_sri = mean(sri))`